# Implement a way to return the headers by overriding spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to know if there is a way to create my own custom annotation.

What I want to do is to create an annotation that with a given name and a value, puts that key on my headers.

This is custom annotation prototype:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ResponseHeader {

String value() default "";

String name() default "";
}
```

And this is what I want to call:

```
public @ResponseHeader(name="Location", format = "/test/id/%s") String test() {
    return UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

What I want to do is by using my custom annotation, overriding the spring functionality to add the to the headers the entry (Location->/test/id/UUID generated) and create a response entity with that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know that maybe my answer doesn't directly answer your question, but to achieve your target, you could :

1. Use HandlerInterceptorAdapter
2. Use ResponseEntity as your API response

```
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/test/id/" + randomId).body(...);
```